# How to join tables by date column with different date format in SQL Vertica?

Tags: sql, date, join, format, vertica

I have two tables in SQL

table1:

```
date        col2
2020-10-25  2
2020-10-20  20
```

table2:

```
date        col1
25.10.2020  1
20.10.2020  10
```

As you can see i have different format of date. My question is how can I in Vertica SQL join this two tables on date column in each table ?

Simply I need to join this two tables by date column co for examplle I need table with 3 columns: date, col1, col2 like below:

result:

```
date        col1  col2
2020-10-25  1     2
2020-10-20  10    20
```

Comment: What are the datatypes for the date columns in the 2 tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a real problem with your data model.  `date`s should be stored using the appropriate date/time type, **not as strings**.

You can convert to a date for the `join`, using:

```
select to_date(t1.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), t1.col1, t2.col2
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on to_date(t1.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = to_date(t2.date, 'DD.MM.YYYY')
```